# Trying to make a decision tree in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a decision tree in javascript using if statements. When you click yes the next question is suppose to pop up, when you click no a bitmoji is suppose to pop up with text. There is three questions being asked but right now you can only see the first question. When I click on "Yes" the next question should pop up but it is not. When I click "No" a bitmoji should pop up and it is also not popping up.

```
var questionNumber = 1; 

var bitmojiX = 346; // position of bitmoji
var bitmojiY = 272; 

var drawBitmoji = function(bitmojiX, bitmojiY) // bitomji drawing
    {
 background(255, 255, 255);
 noStroke(); 

fill(255, 219, 172);
ellipse(bitmojiX,bitmojiY,100,100); //head

fill(144,84,47);
ellipse(bitmojiX,bitmojiY-34,78,38); //top hair
quad(bitmojiX-54,bitmojiY+1,bitmojiX-39,bitmojiY-34,bitmojiX-5,bitmojiY-45,bitmojiX-36,bitmojiY); // left hair
quad(bitmojiX+55,bitmojiY-6,bitmojiX+40,bitmojiY-35,bitmojiX+20,bitmojiY-44,bitmojiX+39,bitmojiY-1); // right hair 

fill(218, 145, 0); // hazel eye
ellipse(bitmojiX-10,bitmojiY,7,5); // left eye 
ellipse(bitmojiX+17,bitmojiY,7,5); // right eye 

stroke(0,0,0);
fill(255, 219, 172);
bezier(bitmojiX,bitmojiY,bitmojiX+21,bitmojiY+22,bitmojiX-8,bitmojiY+20,bitmojiX-4,bitmojiY+15); //nose 

fill(255, 255, 255);
arc(bitmojiX+3,bitmojiY+27,33,14,1,180); //mouth 
line(bitmojiX-14,bitmojiY+27,bitmojiX+19,bitmojiY+27); // top of mouth 

noStroke();
fill(240, 9, 9);
quad(bitmojiX-52, bitmojiY+119, bitmojiX+2, bitmojiY+51, bitmojiX-49, bitmojiY+46, bitmojiX-50, bitmojiY+58); // left shoulder 
quad(bitmojiX+53, bitmojiY+119,bitmojiX+47, bitmojiY+46, bitmojiX-1, bitmojiY+51, bitmojiX+8, bitmojiY+64); // right shoulder 
rect(bitmojiX-37,bitmojiY+50,75,77); // body 

stroke(0,0,0);
rect(bitmojiX-46,bitmojiY-75,92,40); // graduation cap 
fill(0, 0, 0);
rect(bitmojiX-3,bitmojiY-58,5,5); // thingy in center of cap 

stroke(35, 63, 219); // tasel color blue 
line(bitmojiX-64,bitmojiY-17,bitmojiX,bitmojiY-53); // blue tasels 
line(bitmojiX-64,bitmojiY-13,bitmojiX,bitmojiY-53);
line(bitmojiX-64,bitmojiY-23,bitmojiX,bitmojiY-55);

stroke(247, 89, 89); // tasel color red 
line(bitmojiX-64,bitmojiY-20,bitmojiX,bitmojiY-55); // red tasels 
line(bitmojiX-64,bitmojiY-15,bitmojiX,bitmojiY-53);
line(bitmojiX-64,bitmojiY-26,bitmojiX,bitmojiY-55);

fill(255, 215, 0); // gold sash color 
noStroke(); 
quad(bitmojiX-2, bitmojiY+110, bitmojiX-4, bitmojiY+49, bitmojiX-33, bitmojiY+48, bitmojiX-27, bitmojiY+96);
quad(bitmojiX+15,bitmojiY+115, bitmojiX+42,bitmojiY+46, bitmojiX+11, bitmojiY+49,bitmojiX+7, bitmojiY+100); // right sash 

fill(255, 255, 255); // text on body 
textSize(33);
text("TD",bitmojiX-21,bitmojiY+73,400,400); 

}; 


var bitmojiBadDecision = function() // bad decision code
{
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    textSize(30);
    text("Do not buy the car.", 150,381);
};

var bitmojiGoodDecision = function() // goode decision code 
{
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    textSize(30);
    text("Buy the car.", 83,381);
};

 // code for the if statments that when clicked should pop up a bitmoji or the next question 
fill(0, 0, 0);
textSize(15);
text("Buying a car?",30,50); 
    text("Does it cost less than $15,000?", 30, 110); 
    text("Yes", 70,140); 
    text("No", 140,140);
{ 
     
}
var mouseClicked = function(){
if (mouseX>68 && mouseX<72 && mouseY>138 && mouseY<142 && questionNumber===1){
    questionNumber = 2; 
    text("Does it have high MPG?", 30, 170); 
    text("Yes", 70,200); 
    text("No", 140,200);
}
else if (mouseX>138 && mouseX<142 && mouseY>138 && mouseY<142 && questionNumber===1){
    drawBitmoji(bitmojiX, bitmojiY);
    bitmojiBadDecision();
}

if (mouseX>68 && mouseX<72 && mouseY>198 && mouseY<202 && questionNumber===2){
    
    text("Does it have more than 3.5 saftey stars?",30,230); 
    text("Yes", 70,260); 
    text("No", 140,260);
}
else if (mouseX>138 && mouseX<142 && mouseY>198 && mouseY<202 && questionNumber===2){
    drawBitmoji(bitmojiX, bitmojiY);
    bitmojiBadDecision();
```

}

```
if (mouseX>68 && mouseX<72 && mouseY>258 && mouseY<262){
    drawBitmoji(bitmojiX, bitmojiY);
    bitmojiGoodDecision();
}
else if (mouseX>138 && mouseX<142 && mouseY>258 && mouseY<262){
     drawBitmoji(bitmojiX, bitmojiY);
     bitmojiBadDecision();
}
}
};
```

Comment: So, what is your problem? Presuming your `text` function works, and the if statement is inside a mouse event with the parameters such as `mouseX` defined, I don't see anything wrong with this code.

Comment: The way I have it now you see all the text at once and I need the following question to be hidden until it gets clicked on.

Comment: So you want `Does it cost less than $15,000?` to be shown first, and then when the user answers, you want `Does it have high MPG?` to be shown, and so on?

Comment: @AlphaHowl Yes, I just updated it with the new code I have, but I still cant get the follow up questions to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement doesn't wrap your questions:

```js
var questionNumber = 1; 
fill(0, 0, 0);

text("Buying a car?",30,50); 

//                                    Remove the closing brace from here v
if(mouseClicked && mouseX>69 && mouseX<71 && mouseY>139 && mouseY<141) {
    text("Does it cost less than $15,000?", 30, 110); 
    text("Yes", 70,140); 
    text("No", 140,140);
text("Does it have high MPG?", 30, 170); 
    text("Yes", 70,200); 
    text("No", 140,200);
text("Does it have more than 3.5 saftey stars?",30,230); 
    text("Yes", 70,260); 
    text("No", 140,260);
} // ... and put it here
```